# Event on entering the zipcode in cart page

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, zipcode

In cart page, on entering the zip code,an event is triggered to send the following data:

```
{"address":{"region_id":"0","region":"","country_id":"US","postcode":"12345"}}
```

In response, the shipping method and shipping price will get updated.
Now, I want to get the "postcode" so that I can update my custom shipping price in the block. Any help will be appreciated.